# How to change mixed language fields in Word bibliography

Tags: microsoft-word, bibliography

I have created a Word document and added an *IEEE* styled bibliography.
My native language is not English and the bibliography just looks mixed up.

It uses some English words and an English date format, and also uses my native words as well.

[image]

According to this [tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/objects-properties-methods/create-custom-bibliography-styles), there must be an XML holding those fields.

How can I change these fields? Or what should I do about the mixed fields?

Comment: What did you expect the result to look like? That is, what parts are incorrectly formatted? Would it be sufficient for you to change the language of the bibliography to English entirely, or would that cause a problem with some of your native-language sources?

Comment: @NiayeshIsky I expect that everything is in my native language. Unfortunately, the date is in the English format and the Available text is not translated as well. Strangely, the last part is translated again...

Comment: Oh, I see! Well, a bit of roaming tells me that the default bibliography formats are all defined in `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Bibliography\Style`, so you can take a look there. [This page](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-bibliographies) may also give you some ideas. (Specifically, I suspect a solution will have something to do with the LCID.)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to manually set the LCID (locale id) for the bibliography. To do that, you can just use a [field code switch](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/field-codes-bibliography-field-cbb17838-05d7-4533-8066-4791aeddb9de) on the bibliography. The method is as below:

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> to view the field codes. You should see something like `{ BIBLIOGRAPHY }` replace your bibliography. This is the bibliography field code.
- Alter the field code with your desired switch.

  - If you want to force all of your bibliography entries to be displayed in a particular language, use the `\l` switch followed by that language's id (which can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/language-identifier-constants-and-strings) under "Language identifier", but I believe you have to convert the hex number to decimal to get it to work as an argument to the switch).
  - For example, for Hungarian, the hexadecimal value of the LCID is `0x040E`, which in decimal is `1038`, so you have to change the field code to `{ BIBLIOGRAPHY \l 1038 }`.
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F9</kbd> again to hide the field codes.
- Update your bibliography. It should now be formatted with the correct language.

If you want to do this for only one source, though, you can manually change the language of that source in the Manage Sources dialogue box of Word: `References` >> `Manage Sources` >> select desired source to edit >> `Edit...` >> `Language` (top-right corner). If you do this, then you can use the `\f` flag of the bibliography field code to filter out any bibliography entries that are set to a language that isn't Default or the language you want. (This is especially useful if you have a variety of different languages in your bibliography.)

There are other ways to set the LCID values (e.g.: by editing the `Sources.xml` file under `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Bibliography\` directly, as referred to [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/word-2010-change-referencescitation-language/f67a4daf-2af2-40ba-a03c-d28596560e3e)), but these seem to be the easiest ways.

<sub>PS: I believe the field code method will only work if you have the language pack for that language installed (e.g.: I don't have a Hungarian language pack, so this method doesn't seem to work for me with Hungarian, but it does work with languages that I have language packs for). If you don't have the language pack for the language you want and you are not able to download it, this method will likely not work for you.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I checked the field code, and it shows the following: `BIBLIOGRAPHY  \l 1038`. I also checked the Style folder and I can't find any _xml_ file, only some _xsl_ files. In the IEEE xsl file there is only one localizing part that is used for the name of the style (`StyleNameLocalized`). I think I should modify the original xml as the fields are mixed even with the language id set to 1038.

Comment: @Nestor Yup, `.xsl` files are used to [transform XML files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT), so you're looking at the right thing. But if the `\l` flag didn't work, can you check to see what the language of your source is marked as in `Manage Sources` (as explained above)?

Comment: I left it on the Default language settings (it uses the native language) which _should be_ the correct one if every field were translated. I guess the translation is incomplete so it can't translate _Available_...

Comment: @Nestor That's odd! What happens if you force the language in Manage Sources to be the language you want? Also, did you make sure that you have the Hungarian language pack?

Comment: Yes, I have set it to the native language and it is installed (spelling check works and everything else is translated). I aquired another document from a co-worker and his bibliography is _also mixed_ so I'm quite sure that the translation  is incomplete...

Answer (score 0):

A bit late but I also had the same issue. So I will provide my solution here

It is true that the "Available" is simply not translated. But you can translate that word in the xsl file of the style yourself.

To do that go to `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Bibliography\Style` and copy the style you want to translate. In the file give the citation style a different name (ideally do this in a text editor with search and replace) and then go to the word "Available" and change it to whatever it should be in you native language.

This should also work with any other styles than IEEE where some words are not translated.